# Making the image as a background (Send to back)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to have an image in this grid that serves as a background. Any attempt till now at inserting an image control resulted in the image being on top of the buttons while I would like it to be on the back.

```
<Page
x:Class="ZimmerFrei_v0._1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ZimmerFrei_v0._1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid >


    <Button x:Name="btnNearMe" 
            Content="Near Me" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="99,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="76"
            Width="216" 
            Click="btnNearMe_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnBestOffers" 
            Content="Button" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="99,312,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="76" Width="216" 
            Click="Button_Click"/>

    <Image />


</Grid>
```

Comment: XAML renders in order.  So if you put the image first, the buttons should render on top of it.

Comment: If it's 8.1, then [ImageBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx) as your `Grid.Background` will be your friend, if it's not pertaining to 8.1, then you could also simply just move your Image up in your [DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513983%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by making it the first child of your Grid and thus displaying behind your other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing that you can do here is to give your Grid an Image Brush. Simply head to the Brush section in your properties windows and select the Tile Brush there. To the ImageSource property specify the image you want.

You can also check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206969%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more help.

Hope this solves your problem.